# How to replace default certificates on a cloud2edge instance?

Tags: eclipse-hono

I deployed a cloud2edge instance and now i want to replace the default certificates with other ones generated with the `create_certs.sh` script. According to the Hono documentation i can specify the configuration (including the certificates path) in the `values.yaml`, but i am not sure how to do it with the cloud2edge package.

Where should i take a look in order to achieve my goal?

Is there any possibility to set the certificates path without re-installing the package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i did in order to replace the keys/certificate for the mqtt adapter:

Create a secret containing the keys and the certificate

```
kubectl create secret generic mqtt-key-cert --from-file=certs/mqtt-adapter-cert.pem --from-file=mqtt-adapter-key.pem -n $NS
```

Mount the secret into the adapter's container filesystem

```
helm upgrade -n $NS --set hono.adapters.mqtt.extraSecretMounts.tls.secretName="mqtt-key-cert" --set hono.adapters.mqtt.extraSecretMounts.tls.mountPath="/etc/tls" --reuse-values $RELEASE eclipse-iot/cloud2edge
```

Set the corresponding environment variables into the mqtt adapter deployment

```
kubectl edit deployments c2e-adapter-mqtt-vertx -n $NS
```

**YAML:**

[image: YAML screenshot]